# Upgradation of Hibernate version to 4.0.0 from 3.x

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-cache

1. Using jSpaces-1.0.jar to implement Gigaspaces as second level cache. Till, Hibernate 3.6 v it is working fine. When upgrading the version to 4.0, many cache related classes are depricated. How to implement second level cache  using jSpaces-1.0.jar as provider in hibernate 4.0.0 version.
2. Caused by : java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Trace at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.translate error is throwing when adding hibernate 4.0.0 jar dependencies.
   Note: No older version log4j jar  ( <1.12) is present in lib folder .